# How to get type of T generic?

Tags: c#

Here is signature of the function:

```
public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
```

Inside the function I want to check the type:

```
var t = T.GetType();
```

But I get this error:

```
'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context
```

Any idea why I get error and how to get type of T?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof

Comment: GetType() is only valid on an object.  T is not an object, it is a type.  Simply use typeof(T).  Do beware it is a smell, code that needs it is rarely generic code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to get the type of a generic parameter: `typeof(T)`

Comment: Thanks for post.Any idea can I check if T is value type for example int?

Comment: you try this; "typeof(T) is int" it will return bool result

Comment: @Waay: `typeof(T) is Type`! but `typeof(T) == typeof(int)` is true.

Comment: @Michael `typeof(T).IsValueType`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes right

Answer (score 3):

On type names and generic type parameter names given as a C# identifier you can apply the `typeof` operator

```
Type type = typeof(T);
```

on objects you can call the `GetType` method.

```
Type arrayType = array.GetType();
Type elementType = arrayType.GetElementType();
```

Note that `typeof` yields the static type known at compile time, where as `GetType` yields the dynamic type at runtime.

```
object obj = new Person();
Type staticType = typeof(object); // ==> System.Object
Type runtimeType = obj.GetType(); // ==> Person
```

Since `typeof(T)` yields an object of type `System.Type`, you can test for a type with

```
typeof(T) == typeof(Person)
```

or

```
T is Person
```

however; these two comparisons are not equivalent. If you have

```
class Student : Person
{ }
```

And assuming that `T` is of type `Student`, then

```
typeof(T) == typeof(Person)      ===> false, because it is typeof(Student)
T is Person                      ===> true, because every type inheriting Person is a Person
```

The first comparison yields `false`, because we test for equality of the two `Type` objects that are different.